# "A less preferred approach"

Tags: grammaticality, comparatives

I want to indicate that one approach to solve a problem is less preferred than another approach.

How to phrase it correctly?

Is it grammatically correct to state it this way?

> Modeling x and y is a less preferred approach.

Comment: What about "is a disfavored approach"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically correct. I would say "X is a less *preferable* approach than Y", but "X is a less *preferred* approach than Y" is valid, too. The former indicates that the preference is based on objective standards, while the latter implies that there is a specific person or group that actually does the preferring.

Comment: I would actually write it as "...a less-preferred approach."

Comment: @Martha: It's not necessary to hyphenate adverbs, and I'd go so far as to say it looks awkward to do so.

Comment: 'approach' being a noun, surely "less preferred" is functioning as an adjective here, no?

Comment: @Martha: As I understand it, "less preferred" is indeed functioning as an adjective, but "less", being an adverb, binds to the adjective "preferred" rather than to the noun phrase "preferred approach", so a hyphen is superfluous. Generally speaking, a hyphen need only be used when the precedence is otherwise ambiguous ("pink tinted glasses" versus "pink-tinted glasses"), or if the adjective phrase involved is multi-word ("four-year-old boy"). I don't know that many editors would disagree with you, though, and perhaps it's better to err on the side of being explicit.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: ah, ok, I get you now. I do agree that the hyphen in this case is optional.

Comment: @Martha: I love it when conversations on StackExchange sites are civil! StackOverflow can be so brutal.